# Filename List S3 with many users

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, wildcard, filenames

I have an Android and IOS app that uploads images (about 15,000 per minute) to a AWS S3 bucket, everything is all right, but i need to process those images in a web app that is used from 2 to 50 different users called 'Monitores' , when this kind of user logins and begin to process the images the app scan the S3 bucket for the filenames, something like:

```
$recibidos = Storage::disk('s3recibidos');
$total_archivos = $recibidos->allfiles();
```

this generates an array with the files are stored in the time the route is invoked, if i use this with one user for process there is no problem, because the process is one time only, but what if i have 2 or more users trigger this process? the process retrieves no the exact list but i think many of the un processed files will be duplicated.

The process of the filenames is to store in a database and to move to a subdirectory.

For example:

I have 1000 files in the AWS S3 bucket and user1 invoke the process so the array will have 1000 filenames to process, right now the time to process those files is about 3 min, so before the process finish 1000 new files was added to the AWS S3 bucket this files are not in the user1 array, then user2 logins and begins to process, so right now the AWS S3 has new files and old files, then when get the new array gets some old filenames (the ones are not process), in fact when user2 process the files some of this was not available, because the user1 process was made the job.

I need help in this two things:

1.- How to deal with the process. 
2.- How can i use wildcards, because one of the final process changes the filename of the files in S3, so the filename list that i need to process has its exepecific format.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is unclear. What is a 'monitor'? What are you actually trying to achieve? For example, do you need to perform a task on each individual image? Have you considered using Amazon SQS to queue the list of images and then process them from the queue? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks John, i edit my question to clarify my ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about your process, but let's assume:

- You have a large number of incoming images
- You need to perform some operation on each of those instances

There are two recommended approaches to do this:

**Option 1: Serverless**

- Configure the **Amazon S3 bucket** to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created in the bucket
- Create an **AWS Lambda function** as a worker -- it receives information about each file, then processes the file
- AWS Lambda will **automatically scale** to run multiple Lambda functions in parallel. The default is up to 1000 concurrent Lambda functions, but this can be increased upon request.

**Option 2: Traditional**

- Create an **Amazon SQS queue** to store details of images to process
- Configure the **Amazon S3 bucket** to send an event to the SQS queue whenever a new object is created in the bucket
- Use **Amazon EC2 instance(s)** to run multiple *workers*
- Each **worker** reads the file information from the queue, processes the image, then deletes the message from the queue. It then repeats, pulling the next message from the queue.
- **Scale** the number of EC2 instances and/or workers as necessary

Both of these approaches have workers operating on *one image files at a time*, so you do not have the problem of maintaining lists while images being continually added. They are also highly scalable with no code changes.